# Grammar structure

Tags: grammaticality

I'm unable to explain why the following sentence is grammatically correct.

This means that not only **does it** not harm the environment, but it also actually improves it!

What's the difference between saying **does it** or **it does**.

Answer (score 1):

> Not only … but also
>
> We use not only X but also Y in formal contexts:
>
> The war caused not only destruction and death but also generations of
>   hatred between the two communities.
>
> The car not only is economical but also feels good to drive.
>
> This investigation is not only one that is continuing and worldwide
>   but also one that we expect to continue for quite some time.
>
> We can sometimes leave out also:
>
> I identified with Denzel Washington not only as an actor but as a
>   person.
>
> **To add emphasis, we can use not only at the beginning of a clause.
>   When we do this, we invert the subject and the verb:**
>
> Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but also the band was
>   late.
>
> Not only will they paint the outside of the house but also the inside.
>
> When there is no auxiliary verb or main verb be, we use do, does, did:
>
> Not only did she forget my birthday, but she also didn’t even
>   apologise for forgetting it.

(["Not only … but also"
from English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also), Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

Comment: I also learned when a sentence begins with a negative adverb (i.e. Not only) then we inverse the verb and subject similar to what we do when we form a question sentence. Thanks all for the above information.